# With Django, representing foreignkeys in Admin

Tags: python, django

Building a generic app to practice learning with Django.

Two classes in Models:

```
class HouseInformation(models.Model):
        house_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        house_type = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        latitude = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        longitude = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.house_name

class HouseReport(models.Model):
        the_house = models.ForeignKey(HouseInformation)
        visit_date = models.DateField()
```

In Admin view, I'd like to see a list of the houses with the dates they were visited. The admin.py so far is like so, and its not working:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from housing.models import HouseInformation
from housing.models import HouseReport

class HouseReport(admin.ModelAdmin)
        list_display = ('the_house')

admin.site.register(HouseInformation, HouseReport)
```

I hope the one-to-many is represented correctly (one house can have many visits).

Comment: please define "its not working"
Provide the error message you get, or something like that

Comment: SyntaxError at /admin/housing/houseinformation/
invalid syntax (admin.py, line 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the missing `:`:

```
class HouseReport(admin.ModelAdmin):
                                   ^
```

---

Speaking about the task you've initially wanted to solve, check the [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) classes:

> The admin interface has the ability to edit models on the same page as
>   a parent model. These are called inlines.

Add this to the `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from housing.models import HouseInformation, HouseReport


class HouseReportInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = HouseReport

class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        HouseReportInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(HouseInformation, HouseAdmin)
```

And you will see the `House` information and all of the `HouseReport`s associated with a `House` on the `House` admin page.

Comment: I'm getting back, "AttributeError at /admin/housing/houseinformation/
type object 'HouseReport' has no attribute 'validate'"

Comment: @Twitch I've edited the code - check that all of your import statements are the same and you have `admin.site.register` at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the : after the class definition in line 5

```
class HouseReport(admin.ModelAdmin):
```

And you have to write

```
...
list_display = ('the_house',)
...
```

notice the trailing comma? It tells python, that it should create a tuple

Comment: I always wondered what the deal was with the trailing comma in Python! Thank you! Also, this got rid of the errors, but I'm not seeing it listed in the Admin page.